# How to compare each value at the same position from multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, data-comparison

Suppose I have three datasets which have the same form.

```
set.seed(1)
df1<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),15,replace=T),nrow=5))
set.seed(2)
df2<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),15,replace=T),nrow=5))
set.seed(3)
df3<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:4),15,replace=T),nrow=5))

df1              df2               df3
  V1 V2 V3         V1 V2 V3          V1 V2 V3
1  2  4  1       1  1  4  3        1  1  3  3
2  2  4  1       2  3  1  1        2  4  1  3
3  3  3  3       3  3  4  4        3  2  2  3
4  4  3  2       4  1  2  1        4  2  3  3
5  1  1  4       5  4  3  2        4  3  3  4
```

What I wanted to do is to assign a value of 1 to the case that at least one of the three values in the same position from the three datasets is greater than 3, otherwise 0. The output I expect would be

```
newdf
  V1 V2 V3  
1  0  1  0
2  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  1
```

Merging the three datasets into one might be a solution. But, because my data is very huge, I doubt that way is a good idea. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: You really need to add `set.seed` here because `sample` return a different result each time.

Comment: The values of newdf[1,V2] and newdf[2,V1] are correct?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Did you mean I need to use set.seed when I created the random matrices?

Comment: Yes. You need to do something like `set.seed(123)` and then create the data frames and then show their values. Other wise we can't reproduce your data sets.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh. I see. I didn't know that point. Thanks for letting me know! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that will save you merging the data sets

```
(((df1 > 3L) + (df2 > 3L) + (df3 > 3L)) > 0L) + 0L
#      V1 V2 V3
# [1,]  0  1  0
# [2,]  1  1  0
# [3,]  0  1  1
# [4,]  1  0  0
# [5,]  1  0  1
```

Or similarly

```
(Reduce(`+`, list(df1 > 3L, df2 > 3L, df3 > 3L)) > 0L) + 0L
```

---

The idea here is to check each value in each data set if it greater than `3`, then sum up the `TRUE` results, check if the sum is `> 0` and convert to integers by adding `0`. This works because `+` and `>` are generic functions which have a `data.frame` method which preserves the dimensions of the data set, see `?Ops` and more specifically `methods(Ops)`.

Comment: Thanks much David. A quick question is what the 'L' followed by the number means? (I added     set.seed     with your advice. Thanks!)

Comment: The `L` is not necessary I'm just adding it by habit. Also, see my edit , I've mistakenly used `==` instead of `>`

Comment: David. You saved me. It gave the perfect results. Thanks much for this help!!